# Fill in missing timestamp data in elasticsearch database

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a GPS device reporting positions every second.

The positions over time end up being stored in an elasticsearch database as a `geo_point/@timestamp` combination. As is the nature of GPS, a position may not be reported at a particular time (for example if the device loses lock).

What is the best way to fill the missing positions so that I have a position for every `@timestamp`? More specifically, how can I create the missing documents in the elasticsearch database so I have a position value every second?

I have looked into linear interpolation between adjacent points using `elasticsearch-py` and `pandas`, but not had a any luck.

How can I achieve this? Sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, sample code would be greatly appreciated. Please see how to create a [mcve] that way you someone can reproduce your problem and match your output, without guessing about important parts of the problem.

Comment: I have some slight changes to your wording, to make the question more readable. But I agree with the comment you got: you should rather start trying something, and ask us to help with that. Albeit legit, questions asking "show me code that solves my problem" are most often not well received here.

Comment: What if I don't know where to start? I'm not asking any one to provide an exact piece of code for my exact situation. At the moment, anything would help, and then I can go from there.

Comment: if you provide what you intend to do with the data, perhaps create a kibana visualisation, or something else, it would be easier to suggest a solution. What level of detail would you need to present in your output, do you actually need the documents to be present for every second? Perhaps you could use the moving average of the position for the last minute or so?